# Normalising an array of dicts which contain both values directly and other dicts, across whole array

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, normalization

I have a huge array which looks like (example rows):

```
[
        {
            'value':21,
            'openValues':{
                'a':24,
                'b':56,
                'c':78
                }
        },
        {
            'value':12,
            'openValues':{
                'a':98,
                'b':3
                }
        },
        {
            'value':900,
            'openValues':{
                'a':7811,
                'b':171,
                'c':11211,
                'd':4231
                }
        }
        ]
```

And I want to normalise all the values in each key and the values within each dict within a key to be between 0 and 1. So for example:

Here are the calculations to be performed:

```
    [{
       'value':(21-12)/(900-12),
       'openValues':{'a':(24-24)/(7811-24),'b':(56-3)/(171-3),'c':(78-78)/(11211-78)}
     },
     {
       'value':(12-12)/(900-12),
       'openValues':{'a':(98-24)/(7811-24),'b':(3-3)/(171-3)}
     },
     {
       'value':(900-12)/(900-12),
       'openValues':{'a':(7811-24)/(7811-24),'b':(171-3)/(171-3),'c':(11211-78)/(11211-78),'d':(4231-4231)/(4231-4231)}
     }]
```

As you can see, each `value` has been normalised (subtract the minimum value and then divide by the range of values), and same with each key-value pair within `openValues`.

How can I do this?

I want to find a quicker method than having to create additional max/min/range values and dicts, as this has been my existing method (this is an example for calculating the max and min of the `openValues` dict:

```
    openValuesMin = {}
    openValuesMax = {}
    for i, dict in enumerate(array):
        for property,value in dict['openValues'].items():
            if property not in openValuesMax:
                openValuesMax[property] = 0
            if openValuesMax[property]<value:
                openValuesMax[property]=value
            if property not in openValuesMin:
                openValuesMin[property] = 0
            if openValuesMin[property]>value:
                openValuesMin[property] = value

    openValuesRange = {key: openValuesMax[key] - openValuesMin.get(key, 0) for key in openValuesMax.keys()}
```

Is there a one line solution to normalising everything in this way?

Comment: I tried to make your dict readable. That didn't work. your python code is missing a `,` somewhere; It's invalid.

Comment: also: what is your approach? What have you tried? where did you meet problems? **What is your precise question?**

Comment: missing comma on line 16 after ```}```

Comment: Noted, and thanks for changing the formatting @MarcusMüller

Comment: Hi @MarcusMüller I've made the question clearer now, let me know if you need any more clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I've understood your question very well, but assuming you want to normalize between [0-1] considering the min & max values from all posible items in your arrays, here's a possible solution:

```
array = [
    {
        'value': 21,
        'openValues': {
            'a': 24,
            'b': 56,
            'c': 78
        }
    },
    {
        'value': 12,
        'openValues': {
            'a': 98,
            'b': 3
        }
    },
    {
        'value': 900,
        'openValues': {
            'a': 7811,
            'b': 171,
            'c': 11211,
            'd': 4231
        }
    }
]


def normalize(v0, v1, t):
    return float(t - v0) / float(v1 - v0)


def f(v0, v1, item):
    return {
        "value": normalize(v0, v1, item["value"]),
        "openValues": {
            k: normalize(v0, v1, v) for k, v in item["openValues"].iteritems()
        }
    }

values = sum([[item["value"]] + item["openValues"].values()
              for item in array], [])
v_min, v_max = min(values), max(values)
output = [f(v_min, v_max, item) for item in array]
print output
```

EDIT:

If you want to normalize considering values and openValues separately, you could extend the above code like this

```
array = [
    {
        'value': 21,
        'openValues': {
            'a': 24,
            'b': 56,
            'c': 78
        }
    },
    {
        'value': 12,
        'openValues': {
            'a': 98,
            'b': 3
        }
    },
    {
        'value': 900,
        'openValues': {
            'a': 7811,
            'b': 171,
            'c': 11211,
            'd': 4231
        }
    }
]


def normalize(v0, v1, t):
    return float(t - v0) / float(v1 - v0)


def f(vmin0, vmax0, vmin1, vmax1, item):
    return {
        "value": normalize(vmin0, vmax0, item["value"]),
        "openValues": {
            k: normalize(vmin1, vmax1, v) for k, v in item["openValues"].iteritems()
        }
    }

values = [item["value"] for item in array]
v_min0, v_max0 = min(values), max(values)
values = sum([item["openValues"].values() for item in array], [])
v_min1, v_max1 = min(values), max(values)

output = [f(v_min0, v_max0, v_min1, v_max1, item) for item in array]
print output
```

Comment: Hi @BPL this normalises across all the values in the array. I am only looking to normalise each key separately e.g. for the values in `value`, normalise across their range (21-900), and for the values in `openValues: {'a'`, only normalise across their range e.g. 24-7811).

Comment: @DhruvGhulati Ah, ok, I understand now, let me review my question and add a new solution then :)

Comment: @DhruvGhulati Ok, I've extended the code for your function, hope it helps